# how to customize User model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a field to User models in Django.

example in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#I want to add code here that customizes the user model fields.
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/models/) `User` is a superset of `AbstractUser` model. Where the model `User` does not have any extra field.

ex from the documentation:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
    model.

    Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

Therefore, nothing can stop you to inherit `AbstractUser` into another model and add some fields as your need:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser): # <----- you will inherit all User fields
    field_one = models.CharField(...)
    some_relation = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, ...)
    . . .
```

Like this you will add more fields to your own customized User model.

Also, you can see that it can be swapped by `AUTH_USER_MODEL` that need to be specified changing the model `User` as the standard authentication model to your `MyCustomUser`.

Having a close look at the `User` model it has specified sub-class Meta that allow change the standard `User` model for your own custom model:

```
   . . .
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL' # <-----
```

Therefore, once you created your `MyCustomUser` model and migrated it, go to `settings.py` and add the following code into it:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyCustomUser'
```

Now your custom user model is recognized as the standard authentication model by Django with your custom fields.